# Does a laptop antenna need to be marked as 6Ghz to work with a Wifi 6 card?

Tags: bluetooth, computer-building, laptop-repair, wireless-card

**My Situation**

I bought a new Wi-Fi card for my laptop. The card has Wi-Fi 6 and Bluetooth 5. I need to also replace the old 1x1 antenna with a 2x2 antenna. However, I can't seem to find any internal laptop antennas for sale that are marked as Wifi 6. I found a lot of antennas that were marked as 2.4GHz and 5GHz, but none that were marked as 6GHz. (Wifi 6 uses the 6GHz band, right?)

**First Question**

Does the antenna actually need to be marked as 6GHz, or will any 2x2 antenna work with a Wi-Fi 6 card?

**Second Question**

Similarly, do I need to look for anything special to make sure that the antenna will support the Bluetooth 5 functionality of the card?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: As you're editing the question, maybe add the Wi-Fi card model :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the card's marked Wi-Fi 6, it uses 2.4GHz and 5GHz bands. 6GHz is currently used only with Wi-Fi 6E.

2x2 is for MIMO (multiple input / multiple output) and requires 2 antennas to be able to use 2 simultaneous streams.

As for what kind of antenna works; I'd start by looking at the card manufacturer's specs and website. I'd imagine they have instructions and recommendations. You can probably find compatible antennas just by searching from (online) reseller sites, or googling with the card model number.

[Hardware Recommendations SE site](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) might also be a good resource.